# Get all currently logged in users details in php

Tags: php

I have a PHP web application where user can **login** and **logout** (Session start and cookies are set) and access some pages. Now, I **have to show the list of currently logged in users to the admin.** But after searching on google I am unable to understand the proper and safe way to do this job.

Here is currently my thought and its limitations.

1. each time user login, a login record with dateTime will be created
2. each time user logout, a logout record should be created with dateTime
3. Now get currently logged in users by login table enteries

But the **problem with the above approach** is , it is not necessary that every user logout. So I cannot determine the true logged-in users!!!

Do there is any smart approach exists that truly inform me about the currently logged in users.??

Comment: Maybe with a column last_action_time and check last action since 1 hour ago? By that way you could display logged in users in last 1 hour.

Comment: You are talking about something like this https://xlinesoft.com/blog/2015/04/21/displaying-a-list-of-users-that-are-currently-logged-in/ ?? but this is not safe

Comment: Yes, something like that. Why you think it's not safe and what you mean by "safe"?

Comment: where should i update last action? There are several operations in my website where should i update? additionally it is not necessary that user perform an action everytime. He can view the data only.

Comment: That's why you get last action <= 1 hour. If an user is logged in with last action 1 hour ago - it's an idle user, isn't it? You will update last action on every page load.

Comment: "safe" means that it should be true and accurate

Comment: Do you want to see just logged users or logged active users (which are currently on page)?

Comment: what will happen when user only load the page once while the page was open whole day?

Comment: What if I open stackoverflow once and stay open whole day? Am I logged in user - I'm, but inactive - idle. So you need active users, same you can do with "guests". If user load once -> update last action time, on every page load/reload -> update last action time.

Comment: Thanks for example, but once i logged-in stackoverflow i am only reading my question and getting answer update without reloading the page and i am doing this form last 2 hours. I didn't reload the page.

Answer (score 1):

You can put a definition on what constitues a logged in user - for isntance if user was active in some period of time. Then you can log user actions, and see if given user have any actions logged for given period of time.